Serial Web API in Vercel
I have a problem concerning the Serial Web API. When I was deployed my Svelte project on Vercel which had some coding using the Serial Web API, I could not access the reader interface at the top left corner in Chrome anymore in order to access the Serial Port. Locally, on my computer, it did work. So I assume that the issue comes from Vercel itself. Beneath is my code snippet (from app.html) which has the Serial Web API coding. Does someone know why it does not work and how to fix it?
<script>
import { storeData } from "/src/js/store.js";

async function pressEnter(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        try {
            const port = await navigator.serial.requestPort();
            await port.open({ baudRate: 10000 });
            const reader = port.readable.getReader();
            readData(reader);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Fehler beim Verbinden mit dem Serial-Port:", err);
        }
    }
}

async function readData(reader) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            const { value, done } = await reader.read();
            if (done) {
                console.log("Serial port closed!");
                reader.releaseLock();
                break;
            }

            const textDecoder = new TextDecoder();
            const decodedString = textDecoder.decode(value);
            const parsedValue = parseFloat(decodedString);
            storeData.set(parsedValue);
            console.log(parsedValue);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Fehler beim Lesen der Daten:", err);
    }
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter);
</script>

So far, I tried to use different browser since only for some browsers the API works. Maybe I could reach the Serial Port differently but I do not know how.

I don't think this problem is specific to Vercel. Did you try to deploy on another provider, for example?
This is likely a code-level issue, not a platform or server one...
